# I want to move a Git Repository, only one commit.

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm trying to move a git repository to another server, with only a part of the commit history, not all of the history.

Comment: Clone your repository on to another server and type                                  >git log - Copy the commit number till where you would like to keep it          and try  > git reset --hard <commitNumber> . It should change your head to that particular commit.

Answer (score 2):

Use `git checkout --orphan`, to create a new branch without history. Then commit the state that is already added to the index for you and push that branch to the new repository. The result will be exactly what you wanted, a repository with one branch that has one commit.